# I found the variable declaration "UI variableName;" in a java code. What is the meaning of that?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a downloaded java source code of the popular "Connect 6" game. In the user interface classes it uses "UI" in many occasions while there is no class or imported library related. I want to know the reason for that. (Link for the code : http://kevinverhoef.nl/connect6.htm)

```
package userinterface;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import logic.Stone;


/**
* A graphical representation of the board.
* It also handels the mouse clicks on the board for placing human player stones.
*/
public class BoardObject extends JLabel implements MouseListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

UI applet;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public BoardObject(UI applet) {
    Icon c = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("field.GIF"));
    this.setIcon(c);
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 650, 672);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.applet = applet;
}

/**
 * Handles the mouse clicks for placing stone.
 */
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // Offset from the board image.
    int topOffset = 16;
    int leftOffset = 26;

    // determine positions on the field
    int x = (int) Math.floor((e.getX() - leftOffset) / 32);
    int y = (int) Math.floor((e.getY() - topOffset) / 32);

    if (x < 19 && y < 19) {

        // Voeg toe aan bord
        Stone newStone = new Stone(x, y, applet.controller.playingColor);

        // Probeer te plaatsen
        if (newStone.place(applet.board)) {
            newStone.stoneNr = applet.controller.getNextStoneNr();
            applet.drawStones();

            applet.controller.addStone(newStone);

            if (applet.inputEnabled) {
                // Check to see next step
                if (applet.controller.firstStone) {
                    applet.step();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

}
```

Comment: It looks like it is a class in same package

Comment: There is no such class in the source code though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite UI.java is not present in the sources, if you look inside the .jar file, you'll find UI.class in the same package (.jar file can be opened by any .zip archiver). If you are interested in UI.class content use `javap` tool or the latest vesion of Intellij Idea to decompile it.

Answer (score 1):

If `UI` is in the same package as the class using it, it doesn't need to be explicitly imported.

Comment: Maybe whoever made the .zip file just forgot the include the UI.java file.